# Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374), Python, PyCharm

Tags: python, memory, pycharm

I met below message during the testing my code.

```
    Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
```

I am using PyCharm 2016.1.4 and Python 3.4

```
def test():
    code_list = Code_Import()
    for i in range(len(code_list)):
        code_for_sim = Code(i)
        try:
            raw_data = run(code_for_sim)
            profit_table = disparity(raw_data)
            opt_result = Find(profit_table)
            opt_data = dataforsignal(opt_result[0], opt_result[1], raw_data)
            final_data = Data_For_DB(opt_data, opt_result)
            Data_Store(final_data, code_list['Name'][i])
            del raw_data,profit_table,opt_result,opt_data,final_data,
        except: 
            pass
        print(np.round((i / len(code_list)) * 100, decimals=1), '%')
    return
```

I put following code for erase each data after finish iteration for avoiding 
any memory, but not know exact effect. without following code i met memory error message after run around 50%, after put these code, i met title message around 80% processed.

```
del raw_data,profit_table,opt_result,opt_data,final_data,
```

Comment: Please fix the code you posted, it's not properly indented and at least a `def` is missing.

Comment: @Vince I know its been long, do you remember if you were able to fix this code, and how ?